# Unable to statically link boost-locale due to libicu linking errors on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, boost, static-linking, icu, boost-locale

The following code:

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
int main()
{
    using namespace boost::locale;
    generator gen;
}
```

Built with the following flags:

```
g++ -static -static-libstdc++ -pthread main.cpp -lboost_locale -lboost_system -licuuc -licudata -licui18n
```

Fails to link with the following errors:

```
(.text+0x16b8): undefined reference to `icu_60::CacheKeyBase::~CacheKeyBase()'
(.text+0x1c8d): undefined reference to `icu_60::UVector64::~UVector64()'
(.text+0x7dc): undefined reference to `icu_60::UCharsTrie::Iterator::~Iterator()'
...hundreds of other undefined symbols
...(the sample code also has boost linking errors, but let's ignore them, as they only appear in my attempt of reproduction; the real code I have issues with has only icu-related link errors)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, with both `libboost-all-dev` and `libicu-dev` installed from the Ubuntu repositories.
I'm probably missing some trivial component/flag/library needed to make it link together, but am unable to find it.

Comment: Seems like libicu and libicu60 are different packages.

Comment: I also have `libicu60` installed, yes.

Comment: and libicu60-dev? anyway, that's not the correct command. you are linking against icu, not icu60.

Comment: well I am guessing it's just a matter of ordering. Could you try this one and report back: `g++ -static -static-libstdc++ -pthread main.cpp -Wl,--start-group -lboost_locale -lboost_system -licuuc -licudata -licui18n -Wl,--end-group`

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher there is no such package as libicu60-dev. libicu60 is the dependency of libicu-dev (version 60). There's nothing wrong here, just slightly confusing package naming scheme.
@AdamZahran you were right, switching the order of the `-licuuc -licudata -licui18n` part did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Use `-lboost_locale-mt` to replace `-lboost_locale`.